# forward declaration on c++ with a list inside

Tags: c++

I have two clases `Pet` and `Person`

Here is the Person.h:

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H
#include <list>

class Pet;

class Person
{
public:
    Person();
    Person(const char* name);
    Person(const Person& orig);
    virtual ~Person();

    bool adopt(Pet& newPet);
    void feedPets();

private:
    char* name_;
    std::list<Pet> pets_;
};

#endif
```

And here is the Pet.h

```
#ifndef PET_H
#define PET_H
#include <list>
#include "Animal.h"

class Person;

class Pet : public Animal
{
public:
    Pet();
    Pet(const Pet& orig);
    virtual ~Pet();
    std::list<Pet> multiply(Pet& pet);

private:
    std::string name_;
    Person* owner_;
};

#endif
```

The problem that i have is this:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/bits/list.tcc:129: error: invalid use of undefined type `struct Pet'

Person.h:13: error: forward declaration of `struct Pet'
```

I fixed trying to put this `std::list<Pet>* pets_;` but when i tried to call list functions always have a link problem. My question is how a have to include a list inside a class that contains objects from another class.

Comment: In the `cpp` file did you include the headers of the classes you forward declared? meaning in `Person.cpp` do you have `#include  Pet.h`?

Comment: I think the problem is with std::list<Pet>, maybe change it to std::list<Pet*>, this way your .h file wont need complete type. From good coding practive point of view - this is a bad idea to store pointers in list anyway.

Comment: Unrelated: you haven't included `<string>` in your `Pet.h`.

Comment: Adding to Andy's comment above, you should not use `char* name_` on the `Person` type... but rather use `std::string`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard requires that, except where explicitly stated, you use complete types with the library templates. This basically inhibits your design (where each object maintains *by value* a list of the other type).

You can work around this by using [smart] pointers (either a pointer to the container or container of pointers).